# shading a region

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to shade the region bounded by the curve, the tangent and the x axis. Could you help?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.442515197749737655215] 
\draw[line width=1.42pt, ,smooth,samples=1300,domain=-.61851:6.92614618] plot(\x,{\x- ln(1+\x*\x) });
\draw[-> ] (-.8,0)--(7.2469,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[-> ] (0,-1.6)--(0,3.02914275) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[dashed](1,0)--(1,.304);
\draw[fill=red](1,0.306852819440054690582767878541823431924499865639744745879) circle(2.05pt);
\draw(1,-.341624) node {1};
\draw(5,-.341624) node {5};

\draw(-.7314205,.307061)node {$1-\ln 2$};
\draw[dashed](1,0)--(1,0.3044);
\draw[fill=red, dashed, very thin](1,0.306852819440054690582767878541823431924499865639744745879) --(0, .306852819440054690582767878541823431924);
\draw(2.105314205,.98307061)node {$y=x-\ln(x^2+1)$}; 


\draw[line width=.482pt, ,smooth,samples=1300,color=red, domain=-.61851:6.414618] plot(\x,{0.61538*\x-1.335});

\draw[fill=red](1,0.306852819440054690582767878541823431924499865639744745879) circle(1.5pt);
\draw[fill=red](5,1.74119 ) circle(2.05pt);
  \draw[dashed, thin](5,0)--(5,1.74173044);
  \draw[fill=red, dashed, very thin](5,1.749) --(0, 1.749);

  \draw(-.7314205,1.74119)node {$1.7419$};


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a very large number of samples, solutions based on the pgfplots fillbetween library take very long to compile. I therefore propose a different approach. (Not that I nevertheless reduced the number of samples for the straight tangent line to 2, and removed the smooth option.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.442515197749737655215] 
\draw[line width=1.42pt] plot[smooth,samples=131,domain=-.61851:6.92614618] (\x,{\x- ln(1+\x*\x) });
\draw[->] (-.8,0)--(7.2469,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[-> ] (0,-1.6)--(0,3.02914275) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[dashed](1,0)--(1,.304);
\draw[fill=red](1,0.306852819440054690582767878541823431924499865639744745879) circle(2.05pt);
\draw(1,-.341624) node {1};
\draw(5,-.341624) node {5};

\draw(-.7314205,.307061)node {$1-\ln 2$};
\draw[dashed](1,0)--(1,0.3044);
\draw[fill=red, dashed, very thin](1,0.306852819440054690582767878541823431924499865639744745879) --(0, .306852819440054690582767878541823431924);
\draw(2.105314205,.98307061)node {$y=x-\ln(x^2+1)$}; 


\draw[line width=.482pt,color=red] plot
[smooth,samples=2, domain=-.61851:6.414618] (\x,{0.61538*\x-1.335});

\draw[fill=red](1,0.306852819440054690582767878541823431924499865639744745879) circle(1.5pt);
\draw[fill=red](5,1.74119 ) coordinate (aux2) circle(2.05pt);
\draw[dashed, thin](5,0)--(5,1.74173044);
\draw[fill=red, dashed, very thin](5,1.749) --(0, 1.749);

\draw(-.7314205,1.74119)node {$1.7419$};


\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\clip  plot[smooth,samples=131,domain=-.61851:6.92614618] (\x,{\x- ln(1+\x*\x) })
 -- (6,0) -- (0,0);
\fill[blue!20] (0,0) -- (1.335/0.61538,0) --(aux2) -- (0,0 |-aux2) ;

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you will be much better off if you do this with pgfplots and use its fillbetween library.

Comment: I should remove tthe on background layer because Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/on background layer' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \begin{scope}[on background layer]

Comment: @Thumbolt Why? Can't you just add `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` to the preamble of your document? (Otherwise the fill will partly cover the plot curves.)